# When the dynamically created singleton object should be deleted?

Tags: c++, memory, design-patterns, singleton, free

When the dynamically created singleton object should be deleted ? Is it really needed to delete the object explicitly (from destructor) or the not deleted memory will be safely claimed by OS/System once program exits ? What are the consequences if it is not deleted ?

Comment: On a system where the OS frees your memory then it's free'd when the process exits. If not then you need to free it yourself. Also, does the singleton destructor do anything that is needed before process exit? Then you need to explicitly delete the object as well. Or think of a design where you don't really *need* a singleton, especially not a dynamically allocated one.

Comment: It all depends. What is the concrete problem?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The singleton class has a member variable (object of different class) which allocates memory dynamically and deletes it from the desturcutor. But I don't see a explicit delete of the singleton object. Basically I wanted to know what will happen to the member variable if I explicitly delete or don't delete the singleton object.

Comment: It should be deleted when it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is recommended to destroy the object when the application exits. As mentioned in the comments, most OS's will free the memory when the application terminates, but if you need to clean up for example in the destructor of the singleton, then you need to clean it up yourself (OS cleanup will not call the destructor).

I normally delete it just before my application exits, but this is not always the best solution. I have found that in some cases the singleton is created just to be deleted, or accessed after deletion and gets recreated.

You could use the `atexit()` function to register a clean up function when the singleton is created. For example:

```
static Singleton* s_instance = nullptr;

void cleanupSingleton() { 
     delete s_instance;
}


class Singleton {
public: 
    static Singleton* instance() { 
        if(s_instance == nullptr) {
            s_instance = new Singleton();
            std::atexit(cleanupSingleton);
        }
        return s_instance;
     }
 };
```

*PS: not the best, thread safe singleton example but good enough for the example.*

For more information see some references on the `atexit()` function:
[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/) or [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit)

Answer (score 1):

If you use singleton, use Meyers' singleton:

```
class Singleton {
public: 
    static Singleton& instance() { 
        static Singleton s_instance;

        return s_instance;
     }

    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
private:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() { /* Your clean up code */ }
 };
```

Destructor would be called after main ends automatically.